# Can we programatically protect CD/DVD by password?

Tags: c#, access-control, cd, dvd, dvd-burning

I wrote a program to burn CD in C#, but now I want to protect my CD by a password. Is it possible?

Comment: should be possible, but protection would exists if and only if the application is running in that system. We can access when anyone restarts the system or by closing the application. please be specific, what do you want to achieve in what condition?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. One solution would be.

1) Encrypt the real content on the DVD to a file
2) Make a application that decrypts it with your password
3) Add this decrypt application to CD autorun

AutoRun:
Is mostly disabled on machines by now, its default off in Vista+ and was disabled by Windows update in XP recently(And any admin is gonna disable this).

What this normaly means is that Windows will ASK if it should run the autorun application before its started ( Unlike before where it was just started).

Comment: btw, autorun has been disabled by Microsoft on all windows versions in a patch a few weeks ago